# How can I use the keyboard to focus on the git commit message input in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to focus to this input by keyboard rather than mouse click in Visual Studio Code?

[image: Screenshot of VS Code showing the commit message box]

Comment: There was [a vscode issue specifically for this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/44602) that was closed in 2018. However, the final comment mentioned Ctrl + Shift + G, which is currently the default keybinding for Show Source Control—not the commit message specifically—so it is not a solution.

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/125784 is the new issue. Seems like it's supposed to focus when you open the source control view, but doesn't at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, adding my answer found in the following issue, slightly modified:

[Ensure that scm.focus command works in all cases](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/131006#issuecomment-915751155)

Use this keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+e",             // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
    "sequence": [
      "workbench.scm.focus",
      "list.focusFirst",
      "list.select"
    ]
  },
}
```

and the macro extension [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command).

This works whether the scm view is open or not, whether something is already focussed in the scm view or whether a text editor is focussed.

So just the one keybinding, no need to `Home` and `Enter` whether a scm file has focus or not.

Answer (score 7):

While certainly not ideal, I've found the following will focus the Source Control Message input field:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd>
- then, <kbd>ESC</kbd>
- then, <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Now when you repeat <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> it seems to focus the input directly.

Answer (score 6):

As a workaround, we can use the extension `multi`.

Define shortcut like:

```json
    {
        "key": "escape",
        "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
        "args": {
            "sequence": [
                "list.focusFirst",
                "list.select",
            ]
        },
        "when": "listFocus && workbench.scm.active",
    },
```

Answer (score 4):

*For users of [GitLens extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) with the default `"gitlens.keymap": "chorded"` setting:*

If you are in any section in the left menu other than **Source Control** (e.g. **Explorer** or **Extensions**, then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> then press <kbd>G</kbd> again

If you are already in the **Source Control** section of the left menu, then use <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to move focus forward or backward (respectively)

Comment: What's pressing G again supposed to do? For me it searches the changed files.

Comment: The 2nd `G` brings me to the Source Control section. After the Ctrl + Shift + G, it only says at the bottom of VS Code the following: "Waiting for second key of chord". In hindsight, I think the 2nd `G` is needed for me because I have the extension GitLens installed.

Comment: @Jesse yeah, there's a workaround for that posted here: https://github.com/gitkraken/vscode-gitlens/issues/423#issuecomment-398058876

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, according a VS Code maintainer, Ladislou Szomoru ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/193692#issuecomment-1735270417)), <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> (`workbench.view.scm`) should open the Source Control View and focus the commit message input, but there's a known bug that prevents that from happening which should be fixed in the September 2023 release. See [regression: ctrl+shift+g doesn't focus source control anymore when invoked for the first time #184155](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/184155).

---

I have an improved version of [Mark's single-keyboard-shortcut answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69111446/11107541) that also supports when there are multiple open repositories and uses the new [`runCommands`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_running-multiple-commands) feature instead of the multi-command extension:

```json
{
    "key": "", // TODO
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            "workbench.scm.focus",
            "list.focusFirst",
            "list.focusDown",
            // ^ with multiple repositories, there is an additional level of
            //   list nesting for separating by repository. this is to skip
            //   that collapse handle / parent list item
            "list.select",
        ],
    },
    "when": "gitOpenRepositoryCount >= 1",
},
{
    "key": "", // TODO can put the same thing as above
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            "workbench.scm.focus",
            "list.focusFirst",
            "list.select",
        ],
    },
    "when": "gitOpenRepositoryCount == 1",
},
```

Answer (score 1):

First, if needed, focus Source Control with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

Press <kbd>Home</kbd> to focus the message box and <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> to start typing in it.

*<sub>Thanks to [yellowtailfan](https://github.com/yellowtailfan) for bringing this up [on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/125784#issuecomment-1022814834). They specifically said "if one of the changed files has focus", but I don't think that's crucial for <kbd>Home</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> to work.</sub>*

---

Overall, you can navigate the whole Source Control panel like this using direction keys (<kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd>, etc.), which means you can select files, use <kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> to show/hide sections like "Staged Changes", and access more commit options by highlighting that box then using <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move inside it.

Comment: In a previous issue, ArturoDent said "Home" and "Enter" would work when a file has focus in the scm view.  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/131006#issuecomment-915751155.  That guy is brilliant.  See his revised answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TAB/SHIFT+TAB key to move focus in left SOURCE CONTROL panel.

For some color theme you can easily notice where the focus is.

Most of the time the focus is located on the file names in Changes pane(?). In that case press SHIFT+TAB key to move focus to Message field.

Answer (score -4):

Keyboard Shortcuts:  "Source control:Focus on Source Control View"

Comment: That goes to source control, but not to the message.