# How can I focus the git commit message input in the Source Control View of VS Code with a single keyboard shortcut?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, key-bindings, vscode-keybinding

How do I invoke the commit input message box from the Source Control View (using one command/shortcut)? `git.commitall` invokes a floating commit message window.

[image]

The reason I want the one in the Source Control is that it provides the commit history with arrow keys and also shows you the changes underneath.

Comment: so you want that one with the `git.commitall` command? Or you just want whatever keyboard shortcut will focus that one?

Comment: @starball i want the green one with whatever keyboard shortcut, idk which command invokes it, otherwise i'd just use it

Comment: I have moved my answer post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76886742/11107541), since I do not want to have the appearance of double-dipping for reputation (unless someone copies my answer from there back to here under CC-BY-SA (in that case I want to take credit)). I will vote to close this question as a duplicate once the bounty period has ended.

Comment: @starball finally! The answer that works! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

- You can use the short cut key `Ctrl + Shift + G G` to open the source
  control from your active VS Code window.
- You can also find the list of keyboard shortcuts by pressing the `Ctrl + K Ctrl + S` (`File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts`) or you can use the [VS Code cheat sheet](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf) on web for windows.
- Additionally, you can provide your own key bindings for commands by editing the commands and specifying your own short-cut key.

**Update**

How to define your own key bindings?

1- Open the Keyboard Shortcuts by pressing `Ctrl + K` `Ctrl + S`

2- Search for command `workbench.view.scm` or `Source Control`

3- You can define your own key bindings by either clicking on the edit icon (you'll see edit icon when hover over the row) or double clicking on the **Keybindings** column cell of specific command (in this case, `workbench.view.scm`).

4- A popup window will appear with title "**Press desired key combination and then press ENTER**". Here you can press your desired keys from keyboard, e.g. if I press `ctrl + shift + M` at once, and, then press enter, it will be my new key binding (keyboard short cut) for source control

[image]

Comment: But... I did mention that very same shortcut in my answer. I did not mention the  Keyboard Shortcuts, because I did not find any command for that specific view.

Comment: Actually, when I started writing answer, there's no any answer on this post. Any way you can go to the `File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts` from your main menu for all the keyboard short cuts.

Comment: Strange, since I posted my answer 50 minutes before yours ;)

Comment: " I did not mention the Keyboard Shortcuts, because I did not find any command for that specific view.": meaning, there is no command you could find in `File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts` for you to map a shortcut to that "source control" view.

Comment: So, what command should I keybind?)

Comment: @VonC btw, the command for just switching to the Source Control is `workbench.view.scm`

Comment: @cppbest, if you'll see at the key bindings that are already set i.e. ( `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`G` `G`) you can define your own key bindings by double clicking the cursor on **Keybindings** column or clicking on edit icon. Let me update my answer.

Comment: I know how to change keybindings, what I don't know is the command that I need to change in this particular case.

Comment: You've to change this command `View:Show Source Control(workbench.view.scm)` . You can search by either `workbench.view.scm` or `View:Show Source Control`